# setting up a NAS with FreeNAS

Tags: nas, freenas

Forgive me if this question has already been asked, but I'm looking into setting up a NAS using FreeNAS, which has an impressive array of options. Assuming that I am using a m'board with 4 SATA connections, can I use three hard drives in mirror mode and a fourth hard drive independently as a TIME MACHINE for my MAC?

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 1):

3-drive mirror is certainly possible in ZFS, though it seems like a bit of an overkill. And, yes, you can have fourth drive in a separate pool and shared independently [via AFS](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Apple_%28AFP%29_Shares) for use as Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

FreeNAS is insanely flexible; it will have no problem with that configuration of drives.

More generally, be sure you read as much as possible about FreeNAS setup, and ZFS setup in particular.  Seemingly insignificant or harmless settings can kill performance.  Also, give your FreeNAS box as much RAM as it can possibly hold -- 1 GiB per TB of storage is considered a good starting point.